# Search box not working while entering the user's name

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I am working on a project about hospital management system. I have the form of doctor's information.

I am trying to do search the doctor's record by doctor's name but it's not working.

Here is the Sql query that I used for the searching function

```
SELECT Doct_id, doct_name, Doct_speciality, Depart_id, Docter_nic, Doct_phoneno, Doct_picture, Date_of_hiring, Sitting_hours_begin, Sitting_hours_end, Fees FROM dbo.Doctors
WHERE doct_name LIKE @doctName
```

This is the query that i wrote on the doctor's table in my dataSet it takes a parameter `**@doctName**` whose value is from `**textboxItem1**`.

And on the click event of search button that is `**buttonItem1**` the code is

```
 private void buttonItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doctorsTableAdapter.FillBySearch(dataSet1.Doctors,'%'+textBoxItem1.Text+'%');

        }
```

When I write the doctName and click the search button the record doesn't appear on the form.

Comment: have you check that you gets records in sql ?

Comment: you mean that i have record of such doctor or not whom i searched ?

Comment: Which platform do you use? WPF? Winforms? ASP? To what is the doctorsTableAdapter bound, where should the data appear on the form? And, yes, are there reords coming back and just not showing, or is the search itself failing? You are using LIKE, have you checked on its use with your DBMS? Which DBMS?

Comment: i am using Winform and this is a desktop application.no other problem in the form just search itself failing.addition,deletion all other option are working properly..

Comment: Hm, I wonder where `FillBySearch`is defined? I can't find it anywhere, exept a few google hits related to VB..!?  Aslo: What is the Type of `doctorsTableAdapter` ? The various DBMSs are subtly different in various ways including their helper classes; so please tell us which DBMS you are targeting!

Comment: ok I tell you step by step.. I add a data set through solution explorer and then make a replica of my database through server explorer I add a doctor table to the dataset and define the FillBySearch method by adding a query option on doctor table..like in the not connected architecture.

Comment: Actually i am doing my first project thats why i am not better explaining to you @TAW..sorry for that....but Thanks for your response

Comment: You might need to add single quote before the first % sign and after the last % sign. i.e ''%'+textBoxItem1.Text+'%''